# Convert a matrix data model to file data model for Mahout recommendation

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, mahout, mahout-recommender

I have a dataset in the form of a userID, itemID ratings matrix that I am trying to convert to the form {userID, itemID, rating} for use with the Mahout item-based recommender, as described here: https://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/userbased-5-minutes.html#dataset.

In other words, I want to convert something like this:

```
    1   2   3
1   1.0 2.0 3.0
2   4.0 5.0 6.0
3   7.0 8.0 9.0
```

Into something like this:

```
1,1,1.0
1,2,2.0
1,3,3.0
2,1,4.0
2,2,5.0
2,3,6.0
3,1,7.0
3,2,8.0
3,3,9.0
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using Apache Hadoop tools (Pig, Hive, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode` (in hive):

if your input table looks like this:

```
userID item1 item2 item3
----------------------
1      1.0   2.0   3.0
2      4.0   5.0   6.0
3      7.0   8.0   9.0
```

Then your query can be:

```
SELECT userID, split(item_val,'_')[0] as item, split(item_val,'_')[1] as val     
from ( SELECT userID, 
        array(concat_ws('_','item1',item1),
        concat_ws('_','item2',item2),
        concat_ws('_','item3',item3))  as arr from in_table) a
LATERAL VIEW explode(arr) exp as item_val;
```

Explanation: The inner query generates this output:

```
userID                 arr
-----------------------------------------
1      (item1_1.0   item2_2.0   item3_3.0)
2      (item1_4.0   item2_5.0   item3_6.0)
3      (item1_7.0   item2_8.0   item3_9.0)
```

Then after the explode, each line will have userID, itemID and value - only need to split the itemID and the value.

Also, if the table's itemIDs are defined as `double`, you need to `CAST(item2 as string)` before sending them into `concat_ws`.

Comment: When I try this, I'm getting the error "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 6:8 missing EOF at 'VIEW' near 'LATERAL'." The inner query works fine. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Forgot to name the inner table - try now

Comment: That did the trick. Also, the second split should be `split(item_val,'_')[1] as val`